# Isolate Webforms in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application as well as a separate ASP.NET WebForms applicaiton that I inherited separately.  I want to merge the legacy WebForms app into the current MVC application so it all lives in one place (and ease with making changes/publishing).

I've seen many articles and questions about how to add an MVC Area to an older WebForms application, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it properly in the opposite direction.  I want to isolate this legacy WebForms application inside an area of my main MVC application so I can make minor changes as needed as the main MVC application & database evolves.

I know when you create a new MVC Area you get a AreaRegistration.cs file for the routes MVC routes within that area.  Is there a way to implement something similar for embedding the WebForm aspx files?

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  The question is too broad to be answered and most likely is a request for off-site resources.

Comment: @DavidL For real?  There are plenty of questions regarding the correct way to embed a MVC application inside a WebForms app, how is the opposite too broad/request for off-site resources?

Comment: what does it's own routes and config data.  the routes will resolve just like traditional asp.net.  So if you drop form1.aspx at the root of the site, the route will be localhost:xxxx/form1.aspx. As for web.config files you'd need to merge this because they are running from the same application.  you could create a custom config section to keep them separate.  realize asp.net webforms and asp.net mvc is still all asp.net.  it should just work.

Comment: @Fran I tried to make that a bit clearer.  As for the config data looks like creating a custom section is the way to go.

Comment: Areas are a mvc thing.  you should be able to just create a folder like "legacy" and drop all your forms in there and they to partition them off.

Comment: It's pretty much a matter of copying your forms/controls etc over, then manually combining configs and other things common to all ASP.NET projects, such as `global.asax`. There's not really much to ask or answer - just go do it. If you get stuck on a specific part, that might make a better question.